# How to git clone from a docker requirements.txt

Tags: python, git, requirements.txt

I'm trying to setup my application in a docker environment. I have setup a requirements.txt file where it contains the location of the repository and also my username and password. It works just fine previously when all my password was just numerical. But I recently change my password now it contains `#` character. Now it won't read my password. Below is a sample of that

```
git+https://myusername:my#password@bitbucket.org/repository/repository.git#egg=MY_PROJECT
```

now it returns an error

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://myusername:my/': Could not resolve host: myusername
```

I'm guessing it's because of the `#` character after the `my` password. I tried putting a `\` before the `#` character but still no luck. Any workaround on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [%-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) special characters:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.quote('#')
'%23'
```

So your URL has to be

```
git+https://myusername:my%23password@bitbucket.org/repository/repository.git#egg=MY_PROJECT
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks a lot